# Customize category permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

How can I generate URLs like `http://example.com/blog/category/Test/`?

Currently, I have `http://example.com/category/blog/Test/`.

Comment: Is `blog` a category of yours?

Comment: You situation is not clear.
Is "category" in your URL is a real category or have you installed a sub-blog names in a folder called category ? Provide some insight, only then we can present some workaround.

Comment: Please add as much of explanation as you can, It would help the community to help you get the solution with a better explanatory question and also it will increase your chance of getting help.

Comment: yes blog is a parent category. and Test is a category under that parent category. There is also a custom post type named blog.

Comment: Updated my answer, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Permalinks > Custom structure

> blog/%category%/%postname%/

This works for me, it returns:
example.com/blog/category/post-name

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your question? Provide some more detail, e.g. the settings menu, the custom structure box, what the custom structure is for, why this answers the question, and some example URLs?

Comment: I have used it before. But it is not at all working.

Comment: Thanks for replying Jack. But when i am giving the url example.com/blog/ then it is redirecting to the example.com. i have also updated the permalink. But nothing is working.

Comment: That means you have something which is redirecting the user in your .htaccess file.

Comment: This is my .htaccess file.     # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I bet that is the root one. Is there any others?